# How to create dynamic Facebook timeline posts like SoundCloud

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

From just a simple SoundCloud link pasted into my Facebook status update, then Facebook detects that it is a SoundCloud link and embeds a nice SoundCloud player into the post:

[image]

I have inspected the metadata on the SoundCloud page and found only one OpenGraph entry, `og:site_name`:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>SoundCloud - Hear the world’s sounds</title> 
<meta content="record, sounds, share, sound, audio, tracks, music, soundcloud" name="keywords" /> 
<meta content="Explore the largest community of artists, bands, podcasters and creators of music &amp; audio" name="description" /> 
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="dY0CigqM8Inubs_hgrYMwk-zGchKwrvJLcvI_G8631Q" /> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" /> 
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" /> <!--[if IE]> 
<meta content="true" name="MSSmartTagsPreventParsing"> 
<meta content="false" http-equiv="imagetoolbar"> <![endif]--> 
<meta content="19507961798" property="fb:app_id" /> 
<meta content="SoundCloud" property="og:site_name" /> 
<meta content="soundcloud" property="twitter:site" /> 
<meta content="SoundCloud" property="twitter:app:name:iphone" /> 
<meta content="336353151" property="twitter:app:id:iphone" /> 
<meta content="SoundCloud" property="twitter:app:name:ipad" /> 
<meta content="336353151" property="twitter:app:id:ipad" /> 
<meta content="SoundCloud" property="twitter:app:name:googleplay" /> 
<meta content="com.soundcloud.android" property="twitter:app:id:googleplay" /> <link href="/sc-opensearch.xml" rel="search" title="SoundCloud Search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" />   <link rel="icon" href="https://a-v2.sndcdn.com/assets/images/sc-icons/favicon-154f6af5.ico" /> 
<meta name="application-name" content="SoundCloud" /> 
<meta name="msapplication-tooltip" content="Launch SoundCloud" /> 
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="https://a-v2.sndcdn.com/assets/images/sc-icons/win8-38b02b00.png" /> 
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ff5500" /> 
<meta name="msapplication-starturl" content="https://soundcloud.com" />
```

In addition, I can play the music and even more fancy custom things happen:

[image]

I have read about Open Graph, custom actions, objects and so on. I have had a good go at the Facebook documentation and played all through the settings of my custom app, but I can't work out how to emulate the kind of thing SoundCloud has.